# Why in LEX aura:doneWaiting is firing before aura:waiting?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Why in LEX aura:doneWaiting is firing before aura:waiting?

I am showing spinner mask on aura:waiting and hiding it on aura:doneWaiting, and my mask is shown forever because aura:doneWaiting is firing before aura:waiting.

Does anyone know why this happens and if there is any way to overcome this other than refuse using aura:doneWaiting and aura:waiting?